# Unit Test Angular @Input set function not triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

### In my Component

```
@Input('price')
set setPrice(price) {
    this.price = price;
    this.modifyTotalAmount();
}
```

### test (component.spec.ts)

```
it('should call function ', () => {
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'modifyTotalAmount');
    fixture.componentInstance.price = 4500;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const divActualPrice = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#actualPrice'));
    expect(divActualPrice.componentInstance.modifyTotalAmount).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Normally when parent compoent value get changed this ***setPrice(price)*** hits and ***modifyTotalAmount()*** function called. But when unit test runs that ***modifyTotalAmount()*** not called. this test case get faild. I  think what I have done in test case could be wrong. can anyone please clarify whats wrong with this.

Comment: Have you tried calling `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: Is this a spied function? divActualPrice.componentInstance.modifyTotalAmount

Comment: You should be setting the setPrice on line 2 not price property

Comment: You should do some more reading on how `get` and `set` works. I thinks you may have a misunderstanding. You are trying to call the property `price` on the instance. Why do you think this would cause the `setPrice` setter to be called?

Answer (score 3):

As Aniket Kadam already pointed out, when you set 
`fixture.componentInstance.price = 4500` you are not using the setter `setPrice`
that you would need to call in order to trigger `this.modifyTotalAmount()`

So do `fixture.componentInstance.setPrice = 4500` instead.